# Share screen shoot android studio(multi-times)

Tags: java, android, share, screenshot

I have app and i am letting user to make screenshot and share it, all working fine just one problem..

When user for example make screenshot and press on Facebook icon > then he press cancel sharing ,next time when he want to do another share he will see the old screen shoot , how can make it take the last screenshot always??

** i have each image has different file name but the share always taking the last action that didn't finish.
(if user do share all will work fine ,next screen shoot will be the new one )

here is my code

```
 public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
    View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
    rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    return rootView.getDrawingCache();
  }


 public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() , 
"SCREEN"
            + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
  }



 private void shareIt() {
    uri =Uri.fromFile(imagePath);
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
    String shareBody = "جرب تطبيق نكت عراقية مضحكة الان!";
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "تطبيق نكت 
 عراقية مضحكة");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "مشاركة بواسطة"));
 }
```

Comment: Hi there, i just want to ask you about the screenshot part, is this code taking a screenshot of the layout or the home screen of you device?

Comment: is the problem happen only with facebook?

Comment: Just delete the screenshot when take the new one and it's done.

Comment: @Mousa , all the layout ,depends on where you put it , (in which activity mean)

Comment: @layth , Mmm..., thanks but i'm trying to do a screenshot of the home screen of the device.

Comment: @Vlad , I checked with Gmail same problem

Comment: ok, show how you use `saveBitmap` method

Comment: @Andy , i use this way but the user dont know about it , it confuse him

Comment: But you are using the imagePath, and it should always be for the last screenshot, it should work!!!

Comment: @Vlad i call like this way >>>>Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
            saveBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: @MousaAlfhaily, yes it should but it dosnt work ,first i used same file name then changed it but still didnt work

Comment: @layth see my answer it works for me.I always do this for uploading photos.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.Remove the System.currentTimeMillis() from the name of your image so, that you do not have multiple copies of screenshots.So when you upload the image it always have the fresh screenshots.Now when you capture another screenshot you have to check is file exist if exist then delete it.

```
public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "SCREEN.png");
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
    imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() , "SCREEN.png");

    FileOutputStream fos;
    try
    {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: i will try it now

Comment: same problem :(

Comment: Ohh How can it's possible.In this code image is delete when you capture the new one.Then how can it's possible to get the new one.Please make sure the path of your screenshot.

Comment: The problem using your way is app cannot delete old image , I have added these permissions  >>>>> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: any error while deleting the image? Please print the log inside if condition whether it is going into that condition or not.

Comment: The name of the image is not only `"SCREEN.png"`, it's `System.currentTimeMillis() + "SCREEN.png"`.

Comment: I know that.I said just remove the System.currentTimeMillis() and everything works like a charm.

Comment: no error , i have updated the question >>>>Update *** the code work fine when close app and restart it ,even with canceled last share ..

Comment: Because of System.currentTimeMillis()+"SCREEN.png" everytime you capture the screenshot it will always create the new copy.When you remove System.currentTimeMillis() then it will create only one file name with "SCREEN.png" so when you capture the screenshot again then first in my code it will remove the exist file and then generate the new one

Comment: did used the code you gave me but still didnt work , at first it was without System.currentTimeMillis() then i added it myself

Comment: @layth see my updated answer replace this function with your and its done.

Comment: I will try it now

Comment: Same problem , it looks like "share it" keep using old image always that user canceled sharing action

Comment: @layth please tell me imagePath is the static object?