# How to reset data in createChooser intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, start-activity

When user do share image and press cancel the createchooser keep using information from last call ,even when i he does new share still old informations stored there.
How to reset intent data when user cancel sharing ??

i am using this code for sharing

```
 private void shareIt() {
    uri = Uri.fromFile(imagePath);
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
    String shareBody = "try this app";
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "social share app");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "share by .."));

}
```

Comment: i am nt understand clearly, so when you attempt second time but sharing first time shared data ?

Comment: @MageshPandian ,yes exactly this is the problem ,i see same subject, same body,same image , even if delete image from storage i see it in createChooser in next attemp

Comment: i think you string value nt be update first check all string value are latest or old one, because every time you call shareIt() method it create new Object for Intent so possibly problem in variable

Comment: better you can write log on first line of your method. check it

Comment: @MageshPandian i have posted full code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43657993/share-screen-shoot-android-studiomulti-times?

Comment: I think when there is already data in createChooser values cannot be updated inside it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142965/discussion-between-magesh-pandian-and-layth).

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);

sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image using"));
```

use bove code

put this code to manifest

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are not update your ImagePath, So all the time intent show same Image for share, update imagePath before call shareIt() method**

Comment: I checked using log , URI always taking new image path ,but in sharingIntent always first path still there never change till i restart app